# Tkinter adding trace to IntVar in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
class SelectFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, user, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.user = user
        self.main_scrn()
    

    def main_scrn(self):

        menubtn = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Filter", relief="raised")

        menu = tk.Menu(menubtn, tearoff=0)

        for subject in ["math", "english", "physics", "chemistry"]:
            var = tk.IntVar(self, value=0)
            var.trace("w", self.func)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=subject, variable=var)

        menubtn["menu"] = menu

        menubtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

When the `checkbutton` is toggled, the variable trace function is not triggering. The class is inherited from a `tk.Frame`

Comment: I don't have time to test at the moment, but the problem is probably because the variable `var` is a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're using a local variable for the instances of `IntVar`. Tkinter doesn't hold on to a reference, so those variables are cleaned up by the garbage collector when the function returns.

You can verify this by making them global, or an attribute on the object. A simple way to do that is to save them to a list, and make the list an attribute.

In the following example we define `self.vars` as a list, and append each `IntVar` to the list. When you do this, your function will be called each time an item is selected or deselected.

```
class SelectFrame(tk.Frame):
    ...
    def main_scrn(self):

        self.vars = []
        menubtn = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Filter", relief="raised")

        menu = tk.Menu(menubtn, tearoff=0)

        for subject in ["math", "english", "physics", "chemistry"]:
            var = tk.IntVar(self, value=0)
            self.vars.append(var)
            var.trace("w", self.func)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=subject, variable=var)

        menubtn["menu"] = menu

        menubtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

That solves the immediate problem and allows the function to be called each time you select an item, but it becomes difficult to know which values were selected since you have to remember the order of the variables. A way around that problem is to use a dictionary rather than a list. You can then iterate over the dictionary to see which values are selected.

The following example moves the definition of `self.vars` to the `__init__` function, and adds `func` which displays the current values from that dictionary.

```
class SelectFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, user, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.vars = {
            "math": tk.IntVar(value=0),
            "english": tk.IntVar(value=0),
            "physics": tk.IntVar(value=0),
            "chemistry": tk.IntVar(value=0),
        }

        self.user = user
        self.main_scrn()


    def func(self, varname, index, opname):
        for key in self.vars.keys():
            print(f"{key:10}: {self.vars[key].get()}")

    def main_scrn(self):

        menubtn = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Filter", relief="raised")

        menu = tk.Menu(menubtn, tearoff=0)

        for subject in self.vars.keys():
            var = self.vars[subject]
            var.trace_add("write", self.func)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=subject, variable=var)

        menubtn["menu"] = menu

        menubtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because those variables are local variables which will be garbage collected after exiting the function.  You need to use an instance dictionary to store those variables:

```py
class SelectFrame(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def main_scrn(self):
        menubtn = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Filter", relief="raised")
        menubtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        menu = tk.Menu(menubtn, tearoff=0)
        menubtn["menu"] = menu

        self.vars = {}  # an instance dictionary to hold the variables
        for subject in ["math", "english", "physics", "chemistry"]:
            var = tk.IntVar(self, value=0)
            var.trace("w", self.func)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=subject, variable=var)
            self.vars[subject] = var  # save the variable

    # sample func() to show selected subjects
    def func(self, *args):
        print({subject:var.get() for subject, var in self.vars.items()})
```

---

Actually you can use `command` option of `add_checkbutton()` instead of using `.trace()`:

```py
class SelectFrame(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def main_scrn(self):
        menubtn = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Filter", relief="raised")
        menubtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        menu = tk.Menu(menubtn, tearoff=0)
        menubtn["menu"] = menu

        self.vars = {}
        for subject in ["math", "english", "physics", "chemistry"]:
            var = tk.IntVar(self, value=0)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=subject, variable=var, command=self.func)
            self.vars[subject] = var

    def func(self):
        print({subject:var.get() for subject, var in self.vars.items()})
```

Comment: @Swifty i don't have enough "reputation"

Comment: Oh, ok! Then just keep it in mind for later :)